# How do I figure out Data Model for Angular 2/Ionic 2 application

Tags: arrays, ionic-framework, angular, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm working on a travel application in Angular 2/Ionic 2 with Typescript. I need to figure out how to model my services / objects. This app will have users.

Each user can create an overall Trip. You could name it "Europe 2016." Then you could add multiple days to it. They could be be travelling for 14 days. Each day they can have plans on what to do that day including things like what time the activity is, where that activity is, etc... They could also check the weather, add hotel info, etc to each day.

Roughly may be it looks like (sorry this is ugly)

```
Trip: {
  "name": "Europe 2016",
   "tripPlans": [
    {"day1": [{plan1: do something, time: 01000}, {plan2: do something else, time: 01000}}], "time": "0800", "date":"09/01"2016, hotel, weather},
    {"day2": [{plan1: do something, plan2: do something}], "time": "0800", "date":"09/01"2016, hotel info, weather info}
    ]
}
```

Would also need to know the first and last date of trips.

I also may want to go back and query for what the user group find popular, like "most common activity in Gotham"

This is my first major application after spending 100's of hours learning to code and its my personal projects been keeping me excited to learn. It solves a personal problem of mine. I've gotten to the point where I'm having a hard time finding good examples/resources to help me figure this out.

I've sunk a lot of time in to the framework choice so I'd like to stick with it. So far I've landed on trying to use PouchDB/CouchDB. I'm currently only building the mobile version in Ionic right now.

Any advice would be much appreciated even if its github projects to look at, tutorials that you've saved, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mostly work with CouchDB but I've also started to develop an Ionic app with PouchDB/CouchDB.  First of all, you need to know that NoSQL is good when you have a lot of nested documents but sometimes you don't have the choice to make "relations".

First, I reworked a bit your data model :

```
{
    "name": "Europe 2016",
    "type": "trip",
    "tripPlans": [{
        "name": "This is the first plan",
        "days": {
            "day1": [{
                "registeredActivityId": null,
                "plan": "do something",
                "time": 1000
            }, {
                "registeredActivityId": "activty_goToTheMoon",
                "plan": "Go to the moon and the previous activity",
                "time": 1000
            }],
            "time": "0800",
            "date": "09/01/2016",
            "hotel": "Hotel name",
            "weather": "Sunny"
        }
    }]
}
```

Now, you have few options :

1. You can build a view on your nested actives like this one

   ```
    function(doc) {
   if (doc.type == "trip" && doc.tripPlans && doc.tripPlans.join)
       for (var i = 0; i < doc.tripPlans.length; i++) {
           var plan = doc.tripPlans[i];
           if (plan.days)
               for (var n in plan.days)
                   if (plan.days.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
                       var day = plan.days[n];
                       //We emit the activity id for a better tracking.
                       //If it's not available, we emit the description(not recommanded)
                       emit(day.registeredActivityId ? day.registeredActivityId : day.plan);
                   }
       }
   ```

   }
2. You could make relations between your documents

Using the nested approaches make faster query if the views are calculated often. Else, the "relational approach" makes it easier link "predefined activities" for example. You can contact me in private if you need further pieces of information.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to respond! @AlexisCôté It was really helpful.

Comment: @audan2009 Mark this answer as the official answer if it helped you